# Removing the numbers before the text in a code source

Tags: linux

I have like 10000 lines with this format:

```
1 text
2 text
3 text 
...
```

Now, obviously, I don't want the numbers before the text and I think there is a way using linux in order to solve this problem anyone can help please?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the line numbers like so

```
sed -i 's/^[0-9]*\s*//' input.txt
```

Comment: Change it to `s/^[0-9]*//g' to make it work the way he wants to. He does not want to remove *all* numbers, just the line numbers.

Comment: Ah, I did not get the impression that they represented line numbers.Thank you. Updated with your suggestion.

Comment: you may also want to remove the space that appears after the initial number: `sed 's/^[0-9]*\s*//'`. Note also that `g` is not needed here because it will be performed always once, not multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed` for solving it,

```
sed 's/ *[0-9]*.//' file.txt
```

Also the `awk` alternative,

```
awk '{$1 = ""; print $0;}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In vim you can enter column select mode by pressing Ctrl-v (and delete marked text as usual with "d").

After pressing Ctrl-v doing the usual cursor motions -- via cursor keys, page up/down, "G", "gg" etc. -- will select the text "walked over" column wise. That will be most convenient if a fixed number of columns is reserved for numbers, like on Fortran punch cards; if the text shifts right with higher numbers you'll have to remove an additional column for each additional digit (which is only 5 times for 10000). vim has an undo and you can see what you are doing...